# Silverlight fullscreen limitations

Tags: silverlight, browser

When a Silverlight plug-in is in full-screen mode, it disables most keyboard events. They say it is for [security reasons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189023(VS.95).aspx):

> is intended to minimize the
> possibility of unintended information
> being entered by a user

What I don't understand is what is the difference of silverlight fullscreen or any web browser fullscreen?
Is a browser in fullscreen not a security risk too? Anybody complains about the browser fullscreen mode?

Thank you

Comment: For example, you can create a mock Windows (or whatever OS) login screen easier in Silverlight than in a browser.

Answer (score 1):

The full reason for this is that a malicious Silverlight application could create a UI that matches your banking login screen, the Windows login screen, Facebook or whatever site they wanted your login details.

Not only are certain keyboard keys disabled, but full screen cannot be invoked unless there is a user activated action.  For example, the user would have to click a button to go fullscreen, you as a developer are not able to make the app full-screen without this.

This is a pro-active response to known security risks by Microsoft and although there are downsides, the pros do outweigh the cons.